# Error in C2DMReceiver.java for Phonegap Push Notification?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

In phonegap i implemented Pushnotification  for Android.I got REGID from google C2DM server but while Push Message from server to Device Shows Error like 
 "  `FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[man]
     java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message 
     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)`
     at org.phonegap.push.notification.C2DMReceiver.onMessage(C2DMReceiver.java:66)
     `at com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver.onHandleIntent(C2DMBaseReceiver.java:107)
     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)`
I refered code form [Click Here](https://github.com/awysocki/C2DM-PhoneGap) and this Error From C2DMReceiver.java.If anyone know what kind of error reply me to correct Thank u

Answer (score 1):

Double check that your parsing the message correctly. It sounds like your notification is firing correctly? If so then you are trying to log a null value which means you aren't parsing out of the message what you really think you are. It's really annoying but you can get null pointer exceptions from badly implemented logging libs that don't properly handle nulls. Fire up the debugger and inspect what is being logged.